# Need to execute a ruby file from Amazon web service Data pipeline

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

i have a ruby file in my application and i need to call and execute a ruby file as background job from amazon web service data pipeline

i have given the json file below

```
    #json file
    {  "objects": [
    {
      "id": "ScheduleId4",
      "startDateTime": "2013-08-01T00:00:00",
      "name": "schedule",
      "type": "Schedule",
      "period": "15 Minutes"
    },
    {
      "id": "DataNodeId2",
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "ScheduleId4"
      },
      "name": "Input",
      "directoryPath": "s3://pipeline_test/input/",
      "type": "S3DataNode"
    },
    {
      "id": "ActivityId1",
      "input": {
        "ref": "DataNodeId2"
      },
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "ScheduleId4"
      },
      "stdout": "s3://pipeline_test/logs",
      "scriptUri": "s3://pipeline_test/input/sample.sh",
      "name": "Shell",
      "runsOn": {
        "ref": "ResourceId5"
      },
      "stderr": "s3://pipeline_test/logs",
      "type": "ShellCommandActivity",
      "output": {
        "ref": "DataNodeId3"
      },
      "stage": "true"
    },
    {
      "terminateAfter": "1 Hours",
      "id": "ResourceId5",
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "ScheduleId4"
      },
      "name": "Resource1",
      "logUri": "s3://pipeline_test/logs/",
      "type": "Ec2Resource"
    },
    {
      "id": "Default",
      "scheduleType": "timeseries",
      "name": "Default",
      "role": "DataPipelineDefaultRole",
      "resourceRole": "DataPipelineDefaultResourceRole"
    },
    {
      "id": "DataNodeId3",
      "schedule": {
        "ref": "ScheduleId4"
      },
      "directoryPath": "s3://pipeline_test/output1/",
      "name": "Output",
      "type": "S3DataNode"
    }
  ]
}
```

## sample.sh

```
 echo "Hello"
 ruby sample.rb
```

## sample.rb

```
 puts "Hello world"
```

i have given correct path of sample.sh file. Still i am not to get the sample.rb calling or not.
Anyone tell me step by step procedure to follow it as i am newbie to amazon web service datapipeline.

Help me to solve it.

Comment: Can you tell me how you gave the correct path for sample.rb Since, datapipeline will execute the file, you can try to launch a simple bash script that fails if it cannot find the file. That way you can debug faster.

Answer (score 1):

The default image launched by Data Pipeline does not actually have ruby on it.  You'll have to build your own image and install ruby by hand first.  Then, reference that image in your Resource by instanceId